# Django Photo app not displaying

Tags: django

I'm making a photo app using this light bird tutorial .

The problem is , The pictures that I upload . Won't display on the page. 
I have never displayed a picture in django before and I think the problem is with the configuration

[image]

[image]

My models.py

```
  from django.db import models
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  from django.contrib import admin
  from string import join
  import os
  from PIL import Image as PImage
  from mysite.settings import MEDIA_ROOT

  class Album(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
      public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.title
      def images(self):
          lst = [x.image.name for x in self.image_set.all()]
          lst = ["<a href='/media/%s'>%s</a>" % (x, x.split('/')[-1]) for x in lst]
    return join(lst, ', ')
      images.allow_tags = True
  class Tag(models.Model):
      tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.tag

  class Image(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
      image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")
      tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
      albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album, blank=True)
      created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      rating = models.IntegerField(default=50)
      width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
      height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          """Save image dimensions."""
          super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
          im = PImage.open(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.name))
          self.width, self.height = im.size
          super(Image, self).save(*args, ** kwargs)

      def size(self):
          """Image size."""
          return "%s x %s" % (self.width, self.height)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.image.name

      def tags_(self):
          lst = [x[1] for x in self.tags.values_list()]
          return str(join(lst, ', '))

      def albums_(self):
          lst = [x[1] for x in self.albums.values_list()]
          return str(join(lst, ', '))

      def thumbnail(self):
          return """<a href="/media/%s"><img border="0" alt="" src="/media/%s" height="40" /></a>""" % (
                                                                (self.image.name, self.image.name))
thumbnail.allow_tags = True
      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.image.name

  class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      search_fields = ["title"]
      list_display = ["title"]
```

My views.py

```
  from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
  from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
  from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
  from django.core.context_processors import csrf
  from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage, EmptyPage
  from django.forms import ModelForm
  from mysite.settings import MEDIA_URL

  from photo.models import *

  def main(request):
      """Main listing."""
      albums = Album.objects.all()
      if not request.user.is_authenticated():
          albums = albums.filter(public=True)

      paginator = Paginator(albums, 10)
      try: page = int(request.GET.get("page", '1'))
      except ValueError: page = 1

      try:
          albums = paginator.page(page)
      except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
          albums = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

      for album in albums.object_list:
          album.images = album.image_set.all()[:4]

      return render_to_response("photo/list.html", dict(albums=albums, user=request.user,
          media_url=MEDIA_URL))

        class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
            list_display = ["tag"]

        class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
            search_fields = ["title"]
            list_display = ["__unicode__", "title", "user", "rating", "size", "tags_", "albums_",
    "thumbnail", "created"]
            list_filter = ["tags", "albums", "user"]

            def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
                obj.user = request.user
                obj.save()

        admin.site.register(Album, AlbumAdmin)
        admin.site.register(Tag, TagAdmin)
        admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's the problem why the picture didn't show. You call the incorrect and override the path of the image. Remember you have already put function in your model the thumbnail so in your template you must put only:

```
<ul>
    {% for album in albums.object_list %}
    <div class="title">{{ album.title }} ({{ album.image_set.count }} images)</div>
        <ul>
            {% for img in album.images %}
                {{img.thumbnail}}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is correct but my problem is when I test it, the allow tags function has no effect so the output is a link instead of image. So I modified it and got the images show.

```
{% for img in album.images %}
    <a href="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ img.image}}">
        <img border="0" alt="" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ img.image}}" />
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Did you understand my answer? Just ask me if you can't understand.